# How to get data and send data to mLab

Tags: python, json, flask, mlab

I have made a python flask app that I can use to manipulate a scoreboard. The app is hosted on heroku.com. The scoreboard is stored in a JSON file. First I just had the JSON file in the GitHub that Heroku makes for you. But then I found out that every couple of hours Heroku does a reset to your last commit. So any changes I would have made to the scoreboard.json would have been lost.

So I came to the conclusion that I needed to use an actual database hosting site to host my scoreboard.json. I have chosen mLab for this.

What command sends over a complete copy of a file in mLab back to the server so I can make changes to the file and then what command replaces the old file with the new file?

Comment: https://moordspel.herokuapp.com that is the app

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for a python mongodb driver. According to https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/python/:

> PyMongo is the recommended way to work with MongoDB from Python.

Check out the tutorial on using PyMongo, specifically inserting and getting documents.

That being said, you may want to consider splitting up the scoreboard data  into smaller units. For example, having one document per player/team might be easier to manage.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, I will look into inserting and getting documents